# ICreating 2 different layout/design in same page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Recently I am creating a webpage that needs to display 2 different format between desktop and mobile in same page, example: in desktop it shows table and in mobile it shows card view.

Currently I am using "hidden-xs" and "visible-xs" to solve the problem,
but I really want to know about is it the best practice to solve the problem using this kind of method?

Is it the designer fault because of doing 2 version of webpage?

```
<div class="row col-md-12 hidden-xs">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Product Information</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Weight</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        ... php code get data and loop to row
    </tbody>
</table></div>


<div class="row col-md-12 visible-xs">
... php code get data and loop {
    <div>
        <div>$data->Image</div>
        <div>$data->ProductInfo</div>
        <div>$data->Qty</div>
        <div>$data->Weight</div>
        <div>$data->price</div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two different themes one for mobile and another for desktop and then use media query to swap between this two themes.

[alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design) follow this link it will help you to achieve what you want.

Comment: hmm, i am using table tag for desktop but in mobile i cant use table tag because the design is not using table tag.
is it solve-able using media query ?

Comment: it is too customize i think, those 2 just like different thing. and this is just one of the case how about it is not about table but layout is completely different.

Comment: @Wilson if you have included bootstarp in your project in then apply  .table-responsive

Comment: the problem is the design from Designer is not table view for mobile
they want to show table on desktop view and just div (card view) on mobile view.

I can get the design with current code, but i am thinking for the best practice. is it best practice i call or loop data 2 times for 1 thing and just hide and show depend on device resolution?

Answer (score 1):

@media queries is the way to go.

example..

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```

place your changing code within. It is pretty much the best way to achieve this. You can find more information here at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: i know about media query, 
my question is those 2 use different tag but show same thing

in desktop i show those data using <table></table>
but in mobile customer doesnt want the data to show using table, the design for mobile is using div as row and show all column into a div.
that why i create hidden-xs for div that contain table and visible-xs for div that show card view layout

Comment: To help further, could you show some code? It would really help us help you.

Comment: i edited my question for add some sample code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by

Switching the theme when the device has been recognized know.

Comment: what do you mean about switching theme?